# Disable certain types of credentials for CosmosDBTrigger when running locally

Tags: azure-functions, defaultazurecredential, cosmosdbtrigger

I have an Azure Function triggered by a `CosmosDBTrigger`. Internally it seems to use `DefaultAzureCredential` which tries different types of credentials in a specific order. Deployed on the Function App we want to use `Managed Identities`, this works by setting an app configuration `<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__credential` to `managedidentities` as I have seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=cosmos&pivots=programming-language-csharp#local-development-with-identity-based-connections.
In this case it uses the `ManagedIdentityCredential` and does not try first with `EnvironmentCredential` or `WorkloadIdentityCredential`.

Locally, we don't have a managed identity, so it tries the first four types of credentials until it gets to the `VisualStudioCredential` which then works (because I am logged into Visual Studio). This however takes time and it also displays errors when starting up the function as it tries to invoke GetToken for the different types of credentials unsuccessfully.

Usually, you can disable certain types of credentials by do something like this:

```
new DefaultAzureCredential(
    new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
        ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true,
        ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
        ...
    );
```

but I could not figure out how this would work with the `CosmosDBTrigger`.
How can I disable certain types of credentials for the `CosmosDBTrigger` locally?